# "ningún operador "<<" coincide con estos operandos -- los tipos de operando son: std::ostream << Devolver"

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa en C++, y me sale eso al querer mostrar la pila de libros, quiero mostrar una pila de tipo struct, stackdevolv_libro; y no sé cómo solucionar el problema, muchas gracias.

```
void mostrar_libros_devueltos() {
    stack<Devolver> pila_aux = devolv_libro;
    cout<<"----MOSTRANDO LIBROS DEVUELTOS----"<<endl<<endl;
    while (!pila_aux.empty()){
                cout<<pila_aux.top()<<endl; //Aquí se muestra el problema
                pila_aux.pop();        
    }
}
```

Comment: En principio esto no afecta al programa, pero en el primer cout repites el endl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El compilador no es magia, y no sabe de que manera es que quieres impirmir los datos. Tienes que sobrecargar el operador <<.

Tiene que quedarte algo asi:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& o, const Devolver& d) {
  // Usas o como si fuera cout
  return o;
}
```

[Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=msvc-160) lo tienes explicado con mas detalle.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, se agradece.

Comment: @Rodas64 Dale con gusto. Mucha suerte con tu programa

Answer (score 0):

Incluye tu librería string al inicio:
#include 
aquí el link donde encontré la solución: https://foro.elhacker.net/programacion_cc/error_al_usar_cout_string_en_visual_studio-t445621.0.html

Comment: Podrias poner un ejemplo para que así sea una mejor respuesta